# Implementing a clone of the Array concat method

Tags: javascript

Is the following a close representation of how `concat` might be implemented on the Array object?

```js
Array.prototype.myConcat = function(...args) {
    let arr = [...this];
    for (let arg of args) {
        // allow one level of unnesting
        if (!Array.isArray(arg)) arg = [arg,]
        for (let subarg of arg) {
            arr.push(subarg);
        }
    }
    return arr;
};
let x1 = [1,2,3].myConcat('hello', 'new', [1,2,3], [1,2,[3,4]]);
let x2 = [1,2,3].concat('hello', 'new', [1,2,3], [1,2,[3,4]]);
console.log(x1, x2, JSON.stringify(x1) === JSON.stringify(x2));
```

Comment: Isn't this more suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: How close are we talking about here? Because it's not spec compliant. But the edge cases not handled are honestly quite rare - this would be a reasonable implementation if you wanted to cover the exceptionally vast majority of cases.

Comment: looking at lodash https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/ddfd9b11a0126db2302cb70ec9973b66baec0975/lodash.js#L6911